# how to check if start coordinate and current coordinate contains some items on coordinates?

Tags: javascript

i am trying to make a function that has start coordinate and currently focused coordinate, i want to check in those between if they overlap with a distance allowance, i want to do something like:

```
type Coordinate = {x: number; y: number};

export const getHorizontalIntermediate = (
  anchorCoordinate: Coordinate, // start
  focusCoordinate: Coordinate, // current focus
  dimension: number,
  screenCoordinates: Coordinate[], // current coordinates
  hitSlop = 25,
) => {
 // check if some screenCoordinates is between start(anchorCoordinate) and focus(focusCoordinate)
 // with allowance from hitSlop to pass like:
  //     focusCoordinate.x + hitSlop >= anchorCoordinate.x &&
  //     focusCoordinate.x - hitSlop <= anchorCoordinate.x &&
  //     focusCoordinate.y + hitSlop >= anchorCoordinate.y &&
  //     focusCoordinate.y - hitSlop <= anchorCoordinate.y
  ...return the coordinates;
};
```

i am not very sure how to compose this function i am slow with math

Comment: Seems that you are using `typescript` not `javascript`

Comment: yes, just for typechecking but it's actually js logic i need

Comment: Could you kindly add one example with the coordinates. I think I can help.